# VC++ vs. G++, cout

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compilation, g++

I have a question about VC++ 
if u compile this code in VC++ :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

TCHAR lpBuffer[MAX_PATH];

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    DWORD dwBufferLength = 0;
    if(!(dwBufferLength = GetWindowsDirectory(lpBuffer, MAX_PATH)))
        std::cout << "Last error : "<< GetLastError() << std::endl;
    else{
        std::cout << lpBuffer << std::endl;
        /*for(DWORD i = 0; i < dwBufferLength; i++)
            printf("%c", lpBuffer);*/
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

i see only "C" and if i compile it by g++ i will see "C:\Windows" what's the problem?
sure i should delete the first line "#include "stdafx"" under g++ :)

and change "_tmain" to "main" ^__^

Comment: Does G++ recognize the `_tmain` function as the starting function?

Comment: nope, i should write `main` :) thank u  i will change it in my question :)

Comment: You are sending a wide string, a Unicode string, to cout.  You should use wcout instead.  G++ isn't very wide.  You can turn the clock back to the 1980s with Project + Properties, General, Character set = Multi-Byte.

Comment: @HansPassant: Yeaaaaaaaah!!!! thank u  it works :) mmmmmmm but if u put it as answer for i choose it as the best answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

After correcting the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main() {
    char lpBuffer[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD dwBufferLength = 0;

    if(!(dwBufferLength = GetWindowsDirectory(lpBuffer, MAX_PATH)))
        std::cout << "Last error : "<< GetLastError() << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << lpBuffer << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I get identical results ("C:\windows") with both VC++ (2012) and gcc 4.7.2 (MinGW).

Comment: You should add `#include "stdafx"` for it works on VC++, i don't see "C", i see "00ABF608" !!!!!!!!

Comment: @LaVloZ No, you don't need to include *stdafx.h* to compile under VC; you can go to project properties and turn off the precompiled headers option under compiler settings. Jerry, maybe you should call `GetWindowsDirectoryA` explicitly since you're not using any of the TCHAR stuff. That'll make the code work correctly even if the OP has _UNICODE defined.

Comment: aahhhh thank u,  i wasn't know that :) ^__^ i always was fithing with `stdafx.h` because most of time i needn't it :)